# why there are < std_msgs::String> in function name

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the tutorial Writing Publisher Subscriber there is `ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1000);` . 
What I know is that an identifier cant have special characters other than underscore.Then what does this < std_msgs::String > stand here for?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186424/why-there-are-%3C-std_msgs::string%3E-in-function-name/) by [mayank](https://answers.ros.org/users/19704/mayank/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a C++ template argument; the nodehandle advertise function is templated on the topic type, because it can't be inferred from the other function arguments. (Contrast this to the subscribe function, which is also templated, but which can infer the topic type from the type of the callback function)

There's a good [wkikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(C%2B%2B)) about C++ templates, and they should also be covered in any good class on C++.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1